# Oracle OLAP Java implementation - Proper source joining

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-olap

I am trying to achieve the following with the Java API:

[image]

for this purpose I am using the default schema/example GLOBAL from the Oracle OLAP download section.

This is the modified version of the code from the Oracle OLAP Java guide:

```
MdmCube unitsCube =
(MdmCube)mdmDBSchema.getTopLevelObject("PRICE_CUBE_AWJ");
MdmBaseMeasure mdmUnits =
(MdmBaseMeasure)unitsCube.getMeasure("UNIT_PRICE");
NumberSource units = (NumberSource)mdmUnits.getSource();

MdmPrimaryDimension mdmPRODDim = (MdmPrimaryDimension)mdmDBSchema.getTopLevelObject("PRODUCT_AWJ");
MdmLevelHierarchy mdmPRODHier = (MdmLevelHierarchy)mdmPRODDim.getDefaultHierarchy();

StringSource custHier = (StringSource)mdmPRODHier.getSource();

StringSource prodHier = (StringSource)mdmPRODHier.getSource();
Source famSel =
prodHier.selectValues(new String[] {"PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::ACC",
"PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::OS"});
Source querySource2 = units.join(timeSel).join(famSel).join(mdmPRODHier.getSource());
```

The result of the above query is a Cartesian product, and each family is matched with each product hierarchy as:

```
7: (PRODUCT_PRIMARY::CLASS::HRD--------PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::ACC--------CALENDAR_YEAR::YEAR::CY1999--------*35.99375*--------)
8: (PRODUCT_PRIMARY::CLASS::HRD--------PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::ACC--------CALENDAR_YEAR::YEAR::CY2000--------*32.9807070707071*--------)
9: (PRODUCT_PRIMARY::CLASS::HRD--------PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::ACC--------CALENDAR_YEAR::YEAR::CY2001--------*36.8141666666667*--------)
10: (PRODUCT_PRIMARY::CLASS::HRD--------PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::OS--------CALENDAR_YEAR::YEAR::CY1999--------*58.3433333333333*--------)
11: (PRODUCT_PRIMARY::CLASS::HRD--------PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::OS--------CALENDAR_YEAR::YEAR::CY2000--------*62.113125*--------)
12: (PRODUCT_PRIMARY::CLASS::HRD--------PRODUCT_PRIMARY::FAMILY::OS--------CALENDAR_YEAR::YEAR::CY2001--------*65.7258333333333*--------)
```

As we can see here it did a match of the `HRD` (Hardware) with `ACC` (Accessories) and it has a value, but is should not have, as the `ACC` belongs to the class `SFT` (Software). See the attached screenshot for reference.

Is there a way to make an exclusion, so that when I join those two sources, only values that are possible are shown, meaning in this case that the `ACC` would only be shown under the `SFT` class as in the screenshot.

All help is more than welcome,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are joining the same dimension twice. The `PRODUCT_PRIMARY` dimension provides both the class and the family, so when you say:

```
units.join(timeSel).join(famSel).join(mdmPRODHier.getSource());
```

you are first limiting it to just your two `FAMILY` values and then expanding it back out to everything in the `PRODUCT_PRIMARY` hierarchy. The Cartesian product hence matches every product regardless of family, because the final criteria always matches.

I think what you are wanting when you speak of "only values that are possible are shown" you want to be able to drill up and down the hierarchy to find out what the valid children of `HRD` and `SFT` are and what the valid parents of `OS` and `ACC` are. The [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e10795.pdf) explains how to do this with examples starting on page 6-17.